# How to display multibyte character flash message in Laravel7

Tags: laravel

I'm studing contact form with flash message. 
Laravel Framework version is 7.15.0

I can display flash message using below Contoller code.

```
\Mail::send('mail', array(
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
            'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
            'user_query' => $request->get('message'),
        ), function($message) use ($request){
            $message->from($request->email);
            $message->to('mymail@mydomain.com', 'Admin')->subject($request->get('subject'));
        });

        return back()->with('success', 'We have received your message and would like to thank you for writing to us.');
    }
```

I would like to change the flash message as Japanese like below code.

```
 return back()->with('送信完了', 'ありがとうございました');
```

however I couldn't get flash message.

I tried as dobule quote version below but it won't show message.

```
 return back()->with("送信完了", "ありがとうございました");
```

Could you teach me what is wrong my code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
return back()->with('success', 'ありがとうございました');
```